# La calidad creada en Blender no se visualiza con la misma calidad en el navegador

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

El objeto creado en Blender no se visualiza con la misma calidad al mostrarse en el navegador. ¿Qué ocurre?

Izquierda: Imagen en blender.
Derecha: Imagen en el navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Javascript:

```js
//Variables for setup

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let house;
let controls;

function init() {

  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //Create scene
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      const fov = 45;
      const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
      const near = 0.5;
      const far = 1000;

  //Camera setup
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
      camera.position.set(-10, 14.9, 20.5);

      const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 3);
      scene.add(ambient);

      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
      light.position.set(100, 50, 500);
      scene.add(light);

      const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
      light2.position.set(-100, 50, -500);
      scene.add(light2);

  //Renderer
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
      renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Orbit control
      controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  
  //Load Model
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/media/3d/objeto/objeto.gltf', function(gltf) {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        house = gltf.scene.children[0];
        animate();
    });
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    house.rotation.z += 0.0001;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

En general los navegadores Web tienen soporte malo o nulo para la [gestión de color](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesti%C3%B3n_del_color), es un tema complicado y tiene muchas variables, pero creo que en tu caso la Gamma puede estar afectando. Mira [esta documentación](https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/colors.html) al respecto

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Rigo. Siguiendo la documentación que has compartido, veo que hace referencia a una confoguración de color, entiendo que en blender: Image > Input Color Space > sRGB ¿Dónde está esa opción image? (No se si eres usuario de blander. No encuentro esa opción). Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Hola ret, no soy usuario de Blender, conozco de esto porque he sido fotógrafo por una década y sucede los mismo en otros programas, así que no te puedo ayudar en esto. Pero creo que buscando un poco lo encontrarás.